# Get Mutate Error When Applying Purrr::Map on Grouped Data

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

Hi I am trying to apply a very simple function by using `purrr::map` however i keep getting the error `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: unused argument (.x[[i]]).`

The codes are as below:

```
data = data.frame(name = c('A', 'B', 'C'), metric = c(0.29, 0.39,0.89))
get_sample_size = function(metric, threshold = 0.01){

  sample_size =  ceiling((1.96^2)*(metric*(1-metric))/(threshold^2))
  return(data.frame(sample_size))
}
data %>% group_by(name) %>% tidyr::nest() %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(result = purrr::map( .x = data, .f = get_sample_size,  metric = metric, threshold = 0.01 ))
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `nest`. The `metric` argument from `get_sample_size` function should be a numeric vector, but if you do `nest`, the `data` column is a list of data frame, which cannot be the input for the `metric` argument.

I think you can use `summarize` and `map` to apply your function to the `metric` column.

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  summarize(result = purrr::map(.x = metric, 
                                .f = get_sample_size,  
                                threshold = 0.01))
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   name  result              
#   <fct> <list>              
# 1 A     <data.frame [1 x 1]>
# 2 B     <data.frame [1 x 1]>
# 3 C     <data.frame [1 x 1]>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you pass `metric` in the `...` part of `map`, it's not clear that that is a column in the nested data frame. But once you nest the data like you've done, `metric` isn't a column in `data`, it's a column in the nested frame...also called "data." (This is a good example of why you want more specific variable names btw.)

If you're mapping over the `data` column, you can use `$metric` to point to that column, either in writing out a function, as I've done here (such as `df$metric`), or in formula notation (such as `.$metric`).

As @www said, you don't need nested data frames in this case. But for a more complicated case, you might need nested data frames to work with, such as for building models, so it's good to know how to reference exactly the data you want.

```r
library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  tidyr::nest() %>%
  mutate(result = map(data, function(df) {
    get_sample_size(metric = df$metric, threshold = 0.01)
  }))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   name  data             result              
#>   <fct> <list>           <list>              
#> 1 A     <tibble [1 × 1]> <data.frame [1 × 1]>
#> 2 B     <tibble [1 × 1]> <data.frame [1 × 1]>
#> 3 C     <tibble [1 × 1]> <data.frame [1 × 1]>
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>